# How to load Resources that are outside of JAR into MultiResourceItemReader?

Tags: resources, spring-batch

I'm trying to load `Resource[]` into a `MultiResourceItemReader. Running the app locally, I can inject the resources directly as they're contained in the resources directory.

However, the app will be deployed as a jar to a server, at which point the resources (flat files) will be located outside of the jar. I'm having trouble using `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver`-- I keep getting a "No resources found" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MultiResourceItemReader` can read from path outside jar. Just try giving absolute path of the resources.

let say you have input files in ***/data/inputs/csv/*** directory with pattern ***example*.csv***, then in `application.properties` file you can have

```
 input.files.location=/data/inputs/csv/
 input.file.pattern=example*.csv
```

then in the `MultiResourceItemReader` config, you can give as following,

```
@Value("file:${input.files.location}${input.file.pattern}")
private Resource[] inputResources; //thus inputResources will have files matching pattern example*.csv in folder 

@Bean
public MultiResourceItemReader<T> multiResourceItemReader() 
{
    MultiResourceItemReader<T> resourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<T>();
    resourceItemReader.setResources(inputResources);
    resourceItemReader.setDelegate(reader());
    return resourceItemReader;
}
```

Comment: Currently I can load the resources only if they're contained in the src/main/java/resources directory. If they're outside the directory, i.e. located in the root project dir, then I get an error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "Could not resolve resource location pattern [xx]: class path resource [xx] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist"

Comment: please share the code, how you are initialising `MultiResourceItemReader` Bean. I think from the error, you are loading resource from classpath. Please append `file:` before the resource.